# Dynamics 365 BC - Receive and Invoice from PO using API

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

We're using Dynamics 365 BC on Cloud, and successfully tested the API v2.0 to query, filter, update purchase orders / lines.
We now want to "Receive and Invoice" from a PO using API, the same way we do in UI:

- Define a supplier invoice Id
- Set receiveQuantity / invoiceQuantity
- Select "Receive and Invoice"
  => PO updated with adjusted receivedQuantity and invoicedQuantity
  => Supplier invoice created

It seems that this kind of basic action needs custom extension ? Is that correct ?
How to do that ? Could somebody share an example ?

ps: We have found a project on github written by ethan-sorenson ([here](https://github.com/ethan-sorenson/PostOrdersWebService)) but not applicable in our context...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by using the bound action `ReceiveAndInvoice` on the Purchase Orders API.

The endpoint should look (something) like this:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{environment}/api/v1.0/companies({id})/purchaseOrders({id}})/Microsoft.NAV.receiveAndInvoice
```

For more information you can check out [this blog post](https://www.kauffmann.nl/2020/03/05/codeunit-apis-in-business-central/).

Comment: Hi, calling this bound action results in "BadRequest_NotFound". Where did you find this boud action (ReceiveAndInvoice) ? The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/resources/dynamics_purchaseorder) does not mention any bound action available on PO.

Comment: But even in AL language, where to find documentation to manipulate PO / PO lines ?

Comment: I found it in the source code. 
Which version of Business Central are you running on?

Comment: Hi, V 19.1.31886.32222 (Dynamics 365 version). Sorry for this dummy question, but where do you find source code ?

Comment: If you use Docker for development and create a container for your version, then you can find the source code in C:\bcartifacts.cache.

Comment: Here is the source code: https://github.com/microsoft/ALAppExtensions/tree/4519eea4a265dda64dd53c0ff5d60d89333842ad/Apps/W1/APIV2/app/src/pages

Comment: Yes, the bound action exists ( [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/ALAppExtensions/blob/4519eea4a265dda64dd53c0ff5d60d89333842ad/Apps/W1/APIV2/app/src/pages/APIV2PurchaseOrders.Page.al) and should be called using camel case: Microsoft.NAV.receiveAndInvoice

Comment: Perfect. I have edited my answer accordingly.