# Business Central API: Close a Sales Return Order

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

As the heading says I want to close a Sales Return Order form via the API but I have very little information on how to achieve that.

1. A third-party app is installed in the customers Business Central which task is to create return orders from eCommerce into Business Central
2. I have set up a webservice so that my application can get all return orders from the business central
3. The Last step is to close/post all the return orders via the api after the application has handled them.

This is the first time for me working with a sales return order in BC and what I have read is that I can be quite tricky since there is no documentation.

Q:
Do I need to develop an action with AL to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no standard API in Business Central for Sales Return Orders.

This means the answer to your question is: Yes, you must extend Business Central with the requested functionality through AL.

Have a look at how the `ShipAndInvoice` procedure is implemented in the [Sales Orders API](https://github.com/microsoft/ALAppExtensions/blob/main/Apps/W1/APIV2/app/src/pages/APIV2SalesOrders.Page.al). It is basically the same you want to do for Sales Return Orders.

Take a look at [this question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70611624/dynamics-365-bc-receive-and-invoice-from-po-using-api) regarding how to call the bound action on the API.